# How to Connect With Microsoft Localization Center

Tags: windows, unicode, windows-7, localization, keyboard-layout

Windows uses an invalid codepage for keyboard layout in my language, I'm wonderf if there is a way to connect with Microsoft Windows Localization Center and give them the right keyboard layout to put in windows,

I try this in Windows blog (by commenting) and e-mailing with some good guy that I knew but no feedback received.

I'm still want to contact with them and describe the issue,

does any one know a good place or any mail ? any help appriciate

---

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try contacting Michael Kaplan via his [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/).  He works extensively with localization.

Comment: I'd mailed him and also add him as a friend in facebook and try to contact with him but hi didn't answer me. i also try to contact with some other guy that didn't work with microsoft (like Mark Davis) and they didn't feedback me.